# Looking for a KVM Switch for HDMI and USB (Keyboard)

Tags: kvm

I am looking for a KVM switch under $70USD.  All I need to do is switch 2 HDMI ports and 2 USB Ports (for wired Keyboard) into one HDMI and one USB.

I dont need to switch the mouse as I have enough room on teh desk.  I am also not sure how a wireless logitech mouse would switch anyway.

I have looked around, but they either seem to be 500+ or they look too cheap in terms of quality.

---

My usage is Windows desktop primarily.  For a few hours a week, I want to use a raspberry pi gui.  At present I have a separate keyboard and mouse.  I have both hdmi cables plugged into my monitor.  And I go into the monitor's setup to switch the source over.  I do use putty for cli.

Comment: HDMI switches on their own are pretty cheap, and getting a single keyboard and mouse to work on two different computers is possible with software. Would you consider a recommendation like that?

Comment: I would consider any solution.

Comment: @Romen - still keen to hear your recommendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend this [Camgeet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C4PN3SYG)($57): it has good reviews, HDMI 2.1, USB 3, is within budget, and I'm a sucker for metal housing.

Greathtek build's sturdy KVMs. They have a [cheap one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BWRZPXFY)($22), but it's only USB 2. Their [expensive one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BGC46LJ1)($90), is USB 3, but out of your budget.

If you want USB 3 and can settle for HDMI 2.0, there are many clones, but I recommend this [Giimake](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C6GF5S14)($31) because it has it's own power supply.

You can go super cheap with an [HDMI switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K2NZX8L)($12), but then you either need two keyboards, or a software solution. While I have had great experience with [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy), I do NOT recommend using it unless you have separate monitors for each computer.